# Translating query from SQL to EF Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm having trouble translating a SQL query into the appropriate EF query. I'm close but I think I'm missing something with the left join.

Here's my SQL (a slightly contrived example):

```
SELECT
    Count(*), -- count posts
    Tag.Name,
    ISNULL(Category.Name, 'Other')
FROM Post
    INNER JOIN Tag ON Post.TagID=Tag.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Category ON Tag.CategoryID=Category.ID
GROUP BY
    Tag.Name, ISNULL(Category.Name, 'Other')
```

Posts have 0-1 Tags (like I said, slightly contrived example). Tags have 0-1 Categories. So the `INNER` and `LEFT` joins are important.

Here's my not-quite-right EF Query:

```
var counts = ctx.Posts
                .GroupBy(po =>
                            new
                            {
                                Tag = po.Tag.Name,
                                Category = po.Tag.Category.Name ?? "Other"
                            })
                .Select(agg =>
                            new
                            {
                                NumberOfPosts = agg.Count(),
                                Tag = agg.Key.Tag,
                                Category = agg.Key.Category
                            })
                .ToList();
```

This EF query results in this SQL Query, which isn't quite right:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Name], 
    [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Join2].[K1] AS [K1], 
        [Join2].[K2] AS [K2], 
        COUNT([Join2].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent2].[Name] AS [K1], 
            CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[Name] IS NULL) THEN N'Other' ELSE [Extent3].[Name] END AS [K2], 
            1 AS [A1]
            FROM   [dbo].[Post] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Tag] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TagID] = [Extent2].[ID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[CategoryID] = [Extent3].[ID]
        )  AS [Join2]
        GROUP BY [K1], [K2]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

One of the joins is incorrect. Also, I'm not sure if the ISNULL is handled correctly by the GROUP BY or not (it's important since I want it to group with both null values as well as values in the DB with an "Other" value all together as one).

How would I fix this? Or is this just one of those funny scenarios where I need to fall back to something else (a sproc or view)?

VS2017/C#/.NET4.7/EF6.13/SQLAzure

(Edited to add the resulting SQL statement)

Comment: What's the exact issue with your LINQ query? It looks ok to me - as soon as you have a correct entity mappings, EF should generate correct joins for you (through navigation properties). can you post the generated SQL (replace `ToList()` with `ToString()`)?

Comment: @IvanStoev Something is off with my counts. I believe either both joins are coming in as `LEFT OUTER` joins or both are coming in as `INNER` joins. I'm working with randomly generated data so it's not quite obvious to me which and I can't use Profiler to get the queries since I'm hitting Azure. I specifically want the two different types of joins even though cardinalities are the same.

Comment: I see. Most likely both are `left outer join` according to your explanation (the `Optional` relatonship). What about getting the SQL query, you don't need a profiler - just a debugger (see my previous comment :) Anyway, there is no way to force navigation property to generate different join than specified through relationship, so I guess you have to use a manual `join` LINQ query instead of `po.Tag`. Or add `.Where(po => po.Tag != null)` before the `GroupBy`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Updated the question with this info. You're right, they're both `LEFT OUTER` joins. (BTW, neat trick about `ToString`. Somehow I never knew this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the generated joins from reference navigation properties depends of how the navigation property has been setup - `Required` -> `inner join`, `Optional` -> `left outer join`.

Since both your relationships are optional, the generated SQL uses `left outer join`s.

Simply inserting `.Where(po => po.Tag)` will produce a correct result. I was also hoping that EF will be smart enough to turn the corresponding `left outer join` into `inner join`, but it doesn't.

However, inserting intermediate projection and then applying not null filter does the trick:

```
var counts = ctx.Posts
    .Select(po => new { po.Tag })
    .Where(po => po.Tag != null)
    .GroupBy(po => new
    {
        Tag = po.Tag.Name,
        Category = po.Tag.Category.Name ?? "Other"
    })
    .Select(agg => new
    {
        NumberOfPosts = agg.Count(),
        Tag = agg.Key.Tag,
        Category = agg.Key.Category
    })
    .ToList();
```

which generates the desired join types:

```
SELECT
    1 AS [C1],
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2],
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Name],
    [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1],
        [Filter1].[K2] AS [K2],
        COUNT([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Extent2].[Name] AS [K1],
            CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[Name] IS NULL) THEN N'Other' ELSE [Extent3].[Name] END AS [K2],
            1 AS [A1]
            FROM   [dbo].[Post] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tag] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TagId] = [Extent2].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[CategoryId] = [Extent3].[Id]
            WHERE 1 = 1
        )  AS [Filter1]
        GROUP BY [K1], [K2]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

The only redundant is `WHERE 1=1`, but the SQL query optimizer should be able to eliminate it.

Comment: I think this does it. Thanks for discovering that extra projecting causing it to switch the join type. I think I need to play with this a bit for my final non-simplified query (mostly with that projection) but I think I can manage that myself now that I know this approach does it. Thanks!!